# Placeholders not supported in WebBrowser of Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm using WebBrowser to show a log in page,in my application. The problem is that,the placeholders are not supported in it! But it looks fine in my Internet Explorer of my phone.
What could be the problem??

This is the xaml code i'm using for creating WebBrowser,

```
<phone:WebBrowser IsScriptEnabled="True" LoadCompleted="UriContentLoaded" x:Name="browserControl" />
```

How can i change the browser version (i.e to internet Explorer 10)?
Thanks in advance!